# Regexredirect empty - Traefik 2.5.2

Tags: regex, docker, traefik

I have configured the following regexredirect middleware using Docker labels:

```
  - "treafik.http.middlewares.wwwtonone.redirectregex.regex=^https?://(?:www\\.)?(.+)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.wwwtonone.redirectregex.replacement=https://$${1}"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.wwwtonone.redirectregex.permanent=true"
```

If I run the regex through a Go regex validator like regex101.com it is fine.
However, it produces results like this:

```
HTTP/2 308
location: https://example.com/hhttps://example.com/thttps://example.com/thttps://example.com/phttps://example.com/shttps://example.com/:https://example.com//https://example.com//https://example.com/whttps://example.com/whttps://example.com/whttps://example.com/.https://example.com/ehttps://example.com/xhttps://example.com/ehttps://example.com/mhttps://example.com/phttps://example.com/lhttps://example.com/ehttps://example.com/.https://example.com/chttps://example.com/ohttps://example.com/mhttps://example.com/
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 18
date: Fri, 10 Sep 2021 06:41:14 GMT
```

Checking the middleware on the Traefik dashboard gives me this:

[image: dashboard]

The regex portion is empty ... which would indicate why it is giving this weird result.
Does anyone have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

This is on Traefik v2.5.2.

Apologies for the crosspost on the [Traefik form](https://community.traefik.io/t/regexredirect-empty/11721), I asked there first a couple of weeks ago but not a single response.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: It is a simple, global (for all domain names serviced by this Traefik instance) www to non-www redirect. Thus from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.